# How to count pair of values in single query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to count the occurrences of pair values within two fields. For example,

```
Field1 Field2
Value1 Value2
Value2 Value1
```

Values in Field1 and Field2 are considered a pair - they can be interchanged between two fields. My simple aggregate query below groups one way and would return 1 for count. I am wondering if it's possible to group both way using a single query and get 2 for count. I would appreciate any feedback, thank you.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_'id':{'f1':'$Field1','f2':'$Field2'}, 'count':{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{'count':-1}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of gymnastics in an aggregation pipeline and accomplish your goal, but I think a small schema tweak is better. You should store the values of `Field1` and `Field2` in "sorted order", with the smaller value in `Field1` and the larger in `Field2`. That way, grouping on `(Field1, Field2)` will always group together all the docs that would be ideally grouped if you didn't use a "sorted order" and thought of the fields as interchangeable. If it matches other elements of your use case, you could also stored the values of `Field1` and `Field2` in an array, since that is the "most interchangeable way" to store two values because of multikey semantics. You can use [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) to maintain the sort when you add in the two values, if you want.

```
{ "Field1" : "y", "Field2" : "x" }
===>
{ "Field1" : "x", "Field2" : "y" }
OR
{ "Field" : ["x", "y"] }
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up changing the schema as per your suggestion. I am sorry I forgot to thank you properly before